# Retrieve specifc hashtags from Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the JSON result of all the shared posts or statuses with the hashtag of my company name `#company_name`. How can I proceed with this. Currently I have tried with [Facebook Graph Explorer Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) using the built-in access token, but this doesn't seem to give the data.

Comment: There is no API for hash tags. And Post search have been removed in API v2.0

Answer (score 0):

As user WizKid (Software Engineer at Facebook) states in the comments, there is no API for hash tags.

You can search through public posts using Post search in API v1.0 but this is not possible in v2.0.

Comment: currently im using that. (API v1.0)  but most of time it gives not eventhought the values exists .

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23flipbeats&access_token=(add_access_token)  please try this eventhough it doesnt show data  that hashtag contain data on facebook . please advice

Comment: @user3786234 the public post search will be unstable for hashtag searching because that's not the purpose.

Comment: @user3786234 It's **unstable**, there is no advice. The purpose of public posts is not to grab hashtags.

Comment: ok, kindly can u tell me an alternative way for get the details of posts shared on fb with that specifc hash tag

Comment: There is no alternative.